# Getting AccessControlException when instantiating Gson in GAE. why?

Tags: google-app-engine, gson

I'm writing a servlet for GAE that responds with a simple JSON serialization of a POJO.
The thing is, I'm getting `AccessControlException` when I instantiate the Gson object itself, even before instantiating the object I want to serialize (!).

the method:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    MyObject object = new MyObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson(); // here it throws
    String json = gson.toJson(object);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setContentLength(json.length());
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

any ideas?

stacktrace (sorry for the flood):

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:149)
    at com.foodblox.server.RecipeServlet.doPost(RecipeServlet.java:39)
    at com.foodblox.server.RecipeServlet.doGet(RecipeServlet.java:21)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.misc)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1512)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(ClassLoader.java:331)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(ClassLoader.java:329)
    at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.getUnsafe(MappedObjectConstructor.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.<clinit>(MappedObjectConstructor.java:41)
    ... 30 more

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.misc)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1512)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(ClassLoader.java:331)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(ClassLoader.java:329)
    at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.getUnsafe(MappedObjectConstructor.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.<clinit>(MappedObjectConstructor.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:149)
```

---

### Update

- gson revision 730
- GAE 1.4.2

managed to circumvent the problem using this patch:

```
Index: gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/MappedObjectConstructor.java
===================================================================
--- gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/MappedObjectConstructor.java (revision 730)
+++ gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/MappedObjectConstructor.java (working copy)
@@ -57,7 +57,8 @@
   }

   private static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
-    try {
+     return null;
+/*   try {
       Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
       f.setAccessible(true);
       return (Unsafe) f.get(null);
@@ -66,7 +67,7 @@
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       throw new Error();
     }
-  }
+*/  }

   public Object constructArray(Type type, int length) {
     return Array.newInstance(Types.getRawType(type), length);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

sun.misc.unsafe isn't available on GAE. I not positive what the consequences are of commenting out those lines, but my best guess is that you'll run into problems with classes that don't have no-arg constructors.

Comment: bear in mind that this was a workaround for that specific version of GAE SDK. on later versions, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize how old this question was.